# How to find isolated vertices?

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix

Given an adjacency matrix of a simple graph, how do I write a function that enumerates the isolated vertices? (if there are any)

An isolated vertex is a vertex with degree 0.

The adjacency matrix looks like this

```
a, b, c, d, e = range(6)

#     a b c d e f
N = [[0,1,0,0,0,1], # a
     [1,0,1,0,0,0], # b
     [0,1,0,1,0,0], # c
     [0,0,1,0,0,1], # d
     [0,0,0,0,0,0], # e
     [1,0,0,1,0,0], # f
```

Comment: So you're asking how to traverse the graph? Can you define isolated?

Comment: Look for any row in the matrix that consists of all `0`s (if your definition of `isolated` is `not connected with any nodes`)

Comment: an isolated vertex is not an endpoint of any edge and it's a vertex with degree zero

Comment: @inspectorG4dget yes that's what i mean, how do i put that in a function?

Comment: So you iterate over all vertices and check their degrees. If you find a vertex that has degree 0, then you increment a counter to saying you found an isolated vertex.

Comment: This is not an approriate question for SO. Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more info.

Comment: without knowing what your adjacency matrix looks like, we won't be able to give you any code. Why don't you edit your post to include a sample of your adjacency matrix, and what you've tried so far

Comment: @FrankV Out of curiosity, where should this question be asked? I feel it falls under the software algorithm category from the guidelines page.

Comment: @sparkyShorts, that isn't why I say it's not appropriate. It's not appropriate because the question (started out) as "how do I write a function" (no code or even pseudo-code).  The question has since improved but in my opinion, it is still too broad for the SO format.

Answer (score 1):

To find isolated vertices you can form the [degree matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_matrix) of a graph and then look for 0's along the diagonal.  Here are two graph examples:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# star adjacency matrix
star_adj = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
# gr = nx.from_numpy_matrix(star_adj)
# nx.draw(gr)
# plt.show()
```

[image]

We don't expect any isolated vertices in this star graph.

```
iso_adj = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

[image]

This graph's vertex 4 is isolated.

Now I find the degree_list (this list is equivalent to the main diagonal of the degree matrix, but there is no point in making the whole matrix here since all we want are the diagonal entries) by summing the columns of the adjacency matrix (or rows). After that I print indices in this list that are `==0`.

```
def degree_list(adjacency_matrix):
    return np.sum(adjacency_matrix, axis=1)

star_deg = degree_list(star_adj)
iso_deg = degree_list(iso_adj)

print star_deg  # prints: [5 1 1 1 1 1]
print iso_deg   # prints: [2 2 3 1 0]

print [i for i, v in enumerate(star_deg) if v==0]  # prints: []
print [i for i, v in enumerate(iso_deg) if v==0]   # prints: [4]
```

Finally, for the adjacency matrix your post, here is the isolated vertex:

```
c_adj = [[0,1,0,0,0,1], [1,0,1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,1,0,0]]
print [i for i, v in enumerate(degree_list(c_adj)) if v==0]  # prints [4]
```

- The line `i, v in enumerate(blah)` gets the index `i` and value `v` from `blah`, [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 1):

```
#     a b c d e f
N = [[0,1,0,0,0,1], # a
     [1,0,1,0,0,0], # b
     [0,1,0,1,0,0], # c
     [0,0,1,0,0,1], # d
     [0,0,0,0,0,0], # e
     [1,0,0,1,0,0], # f
    ]

d=[ sum(i) for i in N]

print [i for i,v in enumerate(d) if v==0]
```

Thus you get [4] in output and this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is lacking from your question is what you have tried. Come back and post what you have tried so we can help you more, as FrankV  said. However, I'll give a suggestion to start figuring this out:

First of all, you need to iterate over a 2D array (I'm assuming this from your edit), so you know you're going to need a nested for loop. Next, you will need to check in four different directions (error checking for out of bounds indices of course) to see if the vertex has an edge; you will do this for each vertex you iterate over (O(n^2) complexity).

This is a *basic* approach to the algorithm; certainly, there are many other ways to solve this. The first step, though, is to get it to a point where you can understand it and then code it. Come back to it when you have it working correctly, and optimize it.